# MS Azure Linux Diagnostic Extension 3.0 does not post metrics to Azure

Tags: azure

I've installed Linux Diagnostic Extension 3.0 following steps described here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/diagnostic-extension

I see [Guest] metrics appearing in the list of metrics, but no [Guest] metrics values are being posted.

Am I missing something? What could be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a known issue. If you check extension log, you will see error like below:

[image]

The root reason is that Azure Cli 2.0 could not generate sas token contain table.

Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4827) on Github.

A solution to solve this:

You could use Azure Power Shell to generate sas token.

```
$resourceGroup = "shuicli"
$storageAccountName = "shuiclidiag630"
Login-AzureRmAccount
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName 
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$accountSAS = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $ctx
```

Then replace `my_diagnostic_storage_account_sastoken=` to sastoken.

I test in my lab, it works for me.

[image]

Comment: The command `az storage account generate-sas --account-name $my_diagnostic_storage_account --expiry 9999-12-31T23:59Z --permissions wlacu --resource-types co --services bt -o tsv` generate like `ss=b&sp=wlacu&sv=2017-04-17&sig=uc93nbzWheETbFAti2rScRKBXzGSfjALpKU4SQUrgUU%3D&srt=co&se=9999-12-31T23%3A59Z` `ss=b` does not contain `t` table, so, this sas does not have permission to create tables in storage account.

Comment: I see this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/394) on github. The issue will resolve in the future version.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm ready to retest. To clarify: the fix was put in `azure-storage-python`. Is it part of Azure CLI? Should I update Axure CLI before I retest?

Comment: No, `azure-storage-python` this python sdk. I test in latest Azure CLI, it does not work for me. I suggest you could use Power Shell to get sas.

Comment: My joy was, unfortunately, short-lived. The values were coming for about half an hour and then stopped. The only change I've made was re-running the main Bash script under `sudo` because docs said so and I didn't originally. Could it have caused the problem? I also could not achieve success on other servers and for my other project under a different subscription. What could be wrong? Where can I find the extension log? Linux metrics would be really useful for us because we need to troubleshoot a tricky crash / performance issue.

Comment: @DKroot You could check log in `/var/log/waagent.log`. When I test in my lab, I notice the error log.

Comment: @DKroot Sorry for my mistake, I did not set expire time. You need set it. See this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageaccountsastoken?view=azurermps-5.2.0

Comment: Thanks. I've regenerated the token and re-ran the Bash set up script. I took a look on logs, including `/var/log/azure/Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic/3.0.109/extension.log` and the expiration errors went away. I don't see any relevant errors now. However, I get `No metrics could be loaded for the selected resource. If your resource has diagnostics settings, please ensure that they're enabled.` now in the portal. I tried to enable {VM} > Diagnostic settings > Basic metrics to no avail. Is this setting related? Does it need to be on?

Comment: @DKroot By default, `$accountSAS = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $ctx` the token only works for half an hour. I think maybe this is your issue.

Comment: Expiration issue was solved since your previous comment. Now I'm using an expiry date far in the future:

`$resourceGroup = "xxx"
$storageAccountName = "xxx"
Login-AzureRmAccount
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$expiration = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddYears(100)
$accountSAS = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -ExpiryTime $expiration -Context $ctx

echo "Generated SAS token=$accountSAS"`

Comment: @DKroot Thanks for you reply, sorry for my mistake, the token expire time is 1 hour if you don't set it.

Comment: Accepted, thanks! I was able to set up monitoring successfully for 4 servers under one subscription. I still have problems with 2 servers under other subscription. On the first, I get `No metrics could be loaded for the selected resource. If your resource has diagnostics settings, please ensure that they're enabled.`. On the second, set up script failed with `Changing property 'publisher' is not allowed.`. I could not find any error messages in logs. Any advice on these?

Comment: Hi, they are same Linux VM?

Comment: The first problematic VM is Standard D8s v3 (8 vcpus, 32 GB memory). The second is Standard DS4 (8 vcpus, 28 GB memory). Both are running CentOS 7.